# Location and removal of unwanted data

Tags: r

I have mystery data being stored in R and want to get rid of it.

If I start a fresh R session and type data(), it lists some variables
in package '.'

```
Data sets in package ‘.’:

BullsEye                
ClassTest               
Cluster3D               
ComDev10K               
heartatk4R              
Kiviat                  
Kiviat5                 
mhw
```

These are variable names that I used months ago. As far as I can tell, 
I am not loading any .Rhistory or .Rdata files.

Trying to find this, I tried

```
ls()
character(0)

loadedNamespaces()
[1] "compiler"  "graphics"  "tools"     "utils"     "grDevices" "stats"    
[7] "datasets"  "methods"   "base"

search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

But I can type `data(Bullseye)` and load the old data. 
Where is this data being stored and how can I get rid of it?

In case it matters

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1 tools_3.4.1
```

Comment: Is this from Rstudio?

Comment: Another long shot: does your current working directory have a folder called `data`?

Comment: @lmo  - No,  I am using the RGui.

Comment: @joran   Yes!   and all of these names are either csv files or txt files in that directory.  I think that you solved my problem.  Is it documented somewhere that these files are automatically available?

Comment: Yes, it's buried in the Details section of `?data`. They aren't being loaded by default, it's just a quirk of where the function `data()` looks for things when you don't supply any arguments.

Comment: @joran  I see it now.  Thanks for your help.  If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `data()` is called with no arguments, one of the places it ends up looking for data files on disk is in a folder called `data` in the current working directory (if such a folder exists). Specifically, buried in the Details section of `?data` is:

> If lib.loc and package are both NULL (the default), the data sets are
>   searched for in all the currently loaded packages then in the ‘data’
>   directory (if any) of the current working directory.

It sounds like you might have such a folder that contains old data that you've worked on in the past.

Comment: Wow, well done, to both know about and think of this little-known behavior of `data`, it's new to me!